# Why is Edit->Links disabled when I open my sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I want to use the function to see what other spreadsheets a particular file, says `MySS.xls`, is linking to. But somehow the 'Link...' is disabled.

I have unprotected `MySS.xls`.

Why is it so? How can I enable it?

Comment: Are you sure there are links in that particular file?

Comment: @RachelHettinger: that's what I want to find out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Edit: Links button is disabled, the active file has no external links.